# Facebook Tab Redirect / Link

Tags: php, redirect, facebook-page, facebook-apps

```
<?php
    // what shall I do???
?>
```

My big facebook question is, I need to create a tab, similar to the my app tab's with a custom icon etc - which simply redirects to a website outside of facebook, but inside the same window as facebook.

I understand the implications of php redirecting from inside my app canvas, meaning if I try and navigate back one step, it will automatically redirect forward again. To be honsest, that's not really an issue, but I know it's bad practice.

I know how to create custom facebook page apps using the iframe canvas based facebook system, but i'm struggling to figure out what PHP I need to add to my file to redirect as soon as my page is landed on.

I know an empty page will flash before redirecting to an external site, but I don't mind.

Or if there is more forward thinking 'instant' way of achieving this, then great!

Any tutorial pointers or straight code would be hugely helpful as I can't seem to dig anything out of google.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this ?

```
<?php   
  header("Location:http://www.google.com");

?>
```

Comment: thanks mahima for this - will test it tomorrow, looks like what I was after

Comment: hi Mahima, i tried your method. It seems to open page inside the iframe, is there anyway in getting it so the browser loads the page 'http://www.google.com'? Thanks